# Add two or more Tool Window into the same Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions, vspackage

I was trying to add a second tool window to a VSPackage project in Visual Studio, I have a project with a tool window already created usin the wizard provided by Visual Studio when a VSPackage project is created, I was surfing the web looking for some tutorial that can help me adding a second tool window to my existing VSPackage project. I have read several articles about tool windows but I can't get with a solution. I create a new class

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;

namespace Company.VSPackage1
{
    [Guid("759c7eb3-6850-4cce-b765-2d5902a90918")]
    public class OtherToolWindow : ToolWindowPane
    {
        public OtherToolWindow() :
            base(null)
        {
            this.Caption = Resources.OtherToolWindowTitle;
            this.BitmapResourceID = 301;
            this.BitmapIndex = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And then I modify the class that inherited from Package several times but something I'm doing wrong or missing

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;

namespace Company.VSPackage1
{
    [PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true)]
    [InstalledProductRegistration("#110", "#112", "1.0", IconResourceID = 400)]
    [ProvideMenuResource("Menus.ctmenu", 1)]
    [ProvideToolWindow(typeof(MyToolWindow))]
    [ProvideToolWindow(typeof(OtherToolWindow))]
    [Guid(GuidList.guidVSPackage1PkgString)]
    public sealed class VSPackage1Package : Package
    {
        public VSPackage1Package()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Entering constructor for: {0}", this.ToString()));
        }

        private void ShowToolWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ToolWindowPane window = this.FindToolWindow(typeof(MyToolWindow), 0, true);
            if ((null == window) || (null == window.Frame))
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(Resources.CanNotCreateWindow);
            }
            IVsWindowFrame windowFrame = (IVsWindowFrame)window.Frame;
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(windowFrame.Show());

        }

        private void ShowOtherToolWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ToolWindowPane otherWindow = this.FindToolWindow(typeof(OtherToolWindow), 0, true);
            if ((null == otherWindow) || (null == otherWindow.Frame))
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(Resources.CanNotCreateWindow);
            }
            IVsWindowFrame otherWindowFrame = (IVsWindowFrame)otherWindow.Frame;
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(otherWindowFrame.Show());
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine (string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Entering Initialize() of: {0}", this.ToString()));
            base.Initialize();

            // Add our command handlers for menu (commands must exist in the .vsct file)
            OleMenuCommandService mcs = GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;

            if ( null != mcs )
            {
                // Create the command for the tool window
                CommandID toolwndCommandID = new CommandID(GuidList.guidVSPackage1CmdSet, (int)PkgCmdIDList.cmdidMyTool);
                MenuCommand menuToolWin = new MenuCommand(ShowToolWindow, toolwndCommandID);

                CommandID toolwndCommandID2 = new CommandID(GuidList.guidVSPackage1CmdSet2, (int)PkgCmdIDList.cmdidMyTool2);
                MenuCommand menuToolWin2 = new MenuCommand(ShowOtherToolWindow, toolwndCommandID2);

                mcs.AddCommand( menuToolWin );
                mcs.AddCommand(menuToolWin2);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I just want to add more than one tool window in the same vspackage in visual studio

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450237/how-to-add-additional-tool-windows-to-a-visual-studio-extension

Comment: Which is the problem? 1) The command/button for the second toolwindow doesn't appear in Views>Other Windows 2) Clicking the button to create the toolwindow causes "Cannot create window" exception 3) The toolwindow is shown but without the hosted controls 4) ....

Comment: I would avoid posting `Guid`s on the net; since I heard about people who copy/paste code found on SO right into their projects (-:

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong for sure:

```
 CommandID toolwndCommandID2 = new CommandID(GuidList.guidVSPackage1CmdSet2, (int)PkgCmdIDList.cmdidMyTool2);
```

It should be:

```
 CommandID toolwndCommandID2 = new CommandID(GuidList.guidVSPackage1CmdSet, (int)PkgCmdIDList.cmdidMyTool2);
```

And you need to fix the .vsct file and Guids.cs file, which you haven't posted.

That is, a package has a single command set, which can have several commands.

FWIW, I am working on a tutorial about creating toolwindows. Here it is:

HOWTO: Create a toolwindow with a ToolWindowPane class in a Visual Studio package
http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/2015/02/20/mz-tools-articles-series-howto-create-a-toolwindow-with-a-toolwindowpane-class-in-a-visual-studio-package/