# How do i give focus to a WindowPane that hosts a hierarchy of Widows Forms in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio-extensions

i am working on Visual Studio extensions. There is a **WindowPane** that hosts an Editor Window along with a hierarchy of Window Forms, so from one of these Window Forms i am trying to give focus to the open Editor Window by using the Mouse_Click event. I am trying to do this because, if there is any other Auto Hide ToolWindow(like **solution explorer**) visible, the Editor Window does not gain focus on Mouse_Click of the hosted Window Form within the Editor Window.

I have tried the following code, but gives a null reference exception on the IVsWindowFrame.

```
        IVsUIShell vsUIShell = (IVsUIShell)Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsUIShell));
        Guid guid = typeof(SampleEditorPane).GUID;
        IVsWindowFrame vsWindowFrame;
        int status = vsUIShell.FindToolWindow((uint)__VSFINDTOOLWIN.FTW_fFindFirst, ref guid, out vsWindowFrame);

        if (status != VSConstants.S_OK)
            status = vsUIShell.FindToolWindow((uint)__VSFINDTOOLWIN.FTW_fForceCreate, ref guid, out vsWindowFrame);

        if (status == VSConstants.S_OK)
            ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(vsWindowFrame.Show());
```

Is there any other way i can set focus to the active Editor Window?.

Visual Studio also provides a shortcut **ALT + f7** to browser through and select any active Tool Windows.Even if i could implement the above scenario, it would definitely help.

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The following thread provide two method to find related toolwindow, please check if you used from your own package.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414722/how-to-open-a-tool-window-of-a-visual-studio-extension-programmatically

Comment: i get a null reference exception on vsWindowFrame, not sure why this happens even though the SimpleEditorWindow is visible. Maybe the window is not completely initialized.